# Dynamic naming of radio buttons

Tags: php, radio-button

I have "n" number of rows being returned by a sql statement.  Works great.  For every row returned, I would like the user to pick an option (either option 'a' or option 'b')

As standard practice a while loop is used to iterate through each row, and I attempt to name my options by the row number.  However, I run into problems when I attempt to get the value of the radio button the user has selected.

I can't seem to dynamically get the value of the radio button named 1 in the first loop (or any loop with it's appropriate name) of the where clause.

Code snippet here:

```
$counter = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

  echo "<form action='updatepics.php' method='post'>";
  echo "<input type='radio' name='m" . $counter . "' value=  ". $row['f_id'] ."> " . $row['Favorite'];
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='game' value=" . $counter . ">";
  echo " vs " . $row['Underdog'] ." ";
  echo "<input type='radio' name='m" . $counter . "' value=  ". $row['d_id'] ."> ";

  echo "<br>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=" . $_GET["m" . $counter] . " >";
  echo "<input type='submit' value='Make Choice'>";
  echo "</form>";
  $counter ++;
}
```

updatepics.php:

```
Game 
<?php
 echo $_POST['game'];
 echo " " . $_POST['player'] . " picks: ";
 echo " " . $_POST['choice'] ;
 ?>
```

output of updatepics.php...
      Game 1 granny picks:

Notice 'choice' is null

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Can you post the PHP for `updatepics.php`, too, please?

Comment: Are you sure `$_GET[$counter]` is set?

Comment: You're talking about the line with `echo "<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=" . $_GET[$counter] . " >";`?

Comment: 1) I will review the new approaches - ty.  2) updatepics.php just have echo statements to ensure that the variables are passed correctly, but I'll post.  3) $counter is set and for every row tht I 'Make Choice', the appropriate number is passed to updatepics.php.  4) yes, sorry for not being clear enough... I'm looking to see why 'choice' is not getting the value selected by the user in echo "<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=" . $_GET[$counter] . " >";

Comment: updatepics.php: <?php
 echo $_POST['game'];
 echo " " . $_POST['player'] . " picks: ";
 echo " " . $_POST['choice'] ;
?

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML4 specification, [names attributes are defined as CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-INPUT) and [CDATA is defined as follows](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Modify your code to have all name values start with at least one letter.

Comment: I tried that before (didn't want to burden the original post with everything that I had tried).  Let me try again...

Comment: echo "<input type='radio' name=m" . $counter . " value=  ". $row['f_id'] ."> " . $row['Favorite'];
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='game' value=" . $counter . ">";
   echo " vs " . $row['Underdog'] ." ";
   echo "<input type='radio' name=m" . $counter . " value=  ". $row['d_id'] ."> ";
   //echo "  " . $row['line'];

   echo "<br>";
   echo $_GET[$counter];
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=" . $_GET['m' . $counter] . " >";
   echo "<input type='submit' value='Make Choice'>";
   echo "</form>";
   $counter ++;

Answer (score 0):

I bailed out from dynamically creating a radio button name.  Now all radio buttons have the same name through each iteration of the loop.

It seems to work passing the correct value at the correct time even if you select all of the buttons are set before hitting the submit button for each iteration.

```
echo "<form action='updatepics.php' method='post'>";

echo "<input type='radio' name='mw' value=  ". $row['f_id'] ."> " . $row['Favorite'];
echo "<input type='hidden' name='game' value=" . $row['f_id'] . ">";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='player' value='" . $user . "' >";
echo " vs " . $row['Underdog'] ." ";
echo "<input type='radio' name='mw' value=  ". $row['d_id'] ."> ";
echo "  " . $row['line'];

echo "<input type='submit' value='Make Choice'>";
echo "</form>";
```

updatepics.php is just as simple, and it works:
   $_POST['mw']